# Convert SQL to Linq using group by

Tags: linq, .net-core

I am beginner in linq, I want to convert this SQL query:

```
select UserId 
from Table 
where sID in (123, 124) 
group by UserId 
having count(distinct sID) = 2
```

I tried like this

```
var abc = obj_map.dbset
                 .where(x => sID.Contains(x.sID.ToString()))
                 .Select(m => UserId)
                 .Distinct()
                 .ToList();
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something more like this:

```cs
int[] sIDs = new[] { 123, 124 };

IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, X>> abc =
    obj_map
        .dbset
        .Where(x => sIDs.Contains(x.sID))
        .GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
        .Where(gs => gs.Count() == 2);
```

Comment: Probably better to use `var` and and provide explicit projection of `UserId` in `Select`.